# How to catch "No error: PDO constructor was not called"

Tags: php, pdo

how can I catch the following error: `No error: PDO constructor was not called`?

My question is **not** how to *solve* the error, but how to **catch** it!

I need that for a PHPUnit Testing Environment.

I was trying to catch it like that, but it simply doesn't work that way.

```php
$pdo = (new \ReflectionClass(\PDO::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

try
{
    $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table");
}
catch (ErrorException $exc)
{
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

the exact (error) message is as follows: `PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called`, but I am not sure, if that is even any type of PHP catchable.

I've already checked [the method `pdo_raise_impl_error()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.3.3/ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.c#L39)[PHP 7.3.3] that is called with the mentioned error message, but I am not wise enough to anticipate what actual type of error it produces...

Can please someone give advise?

Comment: Have you tried: `\Error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use the following code fore my test.
please check the first and the last line of code especially.

thanks to @YourCommonSense!

```php
set_error_handler(function(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, E_ERROR, $errfile, $errline);
});

$this->expectException(ErrorException::class);
$this->expectExceptionMessage("SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called");

/* @var $pdo PDO */
$pdo = (new ReflectionClass(PDO::class))->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table"); // triggers the error.

restore_error_handler();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's a solution you are looking for, but you can always [convert all errors to exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#converting_errors_to_exceptions) with as simple code as

```
set_error_handler(function ($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0)
{
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
});
```

Of course it will make a global error handler, but honestly, I believe every PHP project should have a code like this.

Or at least you can call this handler only temporarily

Comment: Error handler is invoked by any type of error, save for fatals.

Comment: I just tested the above with the OP's code and it worked like a charm. You never stop learning :-)

Comment: thank you, i know about `set_error_handler()`, but since I'd like to catch it within a PHPUnit Test environment, I am not sure, if using it would be a too strong intrusion...

Comment: @emfi well at least you can make this intrusion temporary, bu saving the prebious handler in a variable and then restoring it back after testing PDO.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah. You are welcome to read my article I linked in the answer, it accumulates all my research in the field of PHP error handling. There is even a solution for fatal errors.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Thank you for the hint. Didn't actually think about that. I think, adding that to your answer, would appreciate it very well.